# SQL Query select col1, col2, if col3='xx' then 'yy' else col3, col4 col5??? is it posible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

well i want to do a query as this but i dont know if it is posible

```
Select 
    col1, 
    col2, 
    col3, 
    if(contain(col3,'somethingx')) then 'hello' else 'world' as col4, 
    col5 
from table1
```

In other words, I want to select

```
col1
col2
col3
```

if `col3` contains the word `'somethingx'` then I want to select `'hello' as col4`

Otherwise I want to select `'world' as col5` from my table.

Comment: Have you tried a Case statement?

Comment: have you read about `CASE` statment in T-SQL?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Just to be pedantic about terminology, in T-SQL `CASE` is an *expression* (which returns a scalar value), not a *statement*. Calling it a statement leads people to believe you can use it for control of flow, like you can do with its namesake in VB, which you cannot do in T-SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    col1, 
    col2, 
    col3, 
    CASE WHEN col3 LIKE '%somethingx%' THEN 'hello' ELSE 'world' END AS col4, 
    col5
FROM table1
```